# getting error when observable field is empty

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating an object using following syntax

```
$scope.headerVal = {
                    'usercode': $rootScope.usrCrdntls.getLoginUcode(),
                    'venue': data.VENUECODE(),
                    'symbol': data.SECURITYCODE(),
                    'expirydate':  data.EXPIRATIONDATE(),             
                    'option': data.CALLPUT(),
                    'strikeprice': data.STRIKEPRICE()


            };
```

Where data consists of observable fields. But in some case EXPIRATIONDATE() is not exits. As a result, error is arising. How I can get rid of from this error

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough point for adding comments. So just adding my comments as answer.

I dont have much info about knockout.js. but below  should work.

```
$scope.headerVal = {
                'usercode': $rootScope.usrCrdntls.getLoginUcode(),
                'venue': data.VENUECODE(),
                'symbol': data.SECURITYCODE(),
                'option': data.CALLPUT(),
                'strikeprice': data.STRIKEPRICE()
        };
if (data.EXPIRATIONDATE){
      $scope.headerVal.expirydate = data.EXPIRATIONDATE();
}
```

Add extra check for the field. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check error condition something like below:

```
'expirydate':  function() {
  if( data.hasOwnProperty(EXPIRATIONDATE())) {
    return data.EXPIRATIONDATE();
  }
  else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the one-liner:

```
       $scope.headerVal = {
                'usercode': $rootScope.usrCrdntls.getLoginUcode(),
                'venue': data.VENUECODE(),
                'symbol': data.SECURITYCODE(),
                'expirydate':  data.EXPIRATIONDATE && data.EXPIRATIONDATE(),             
                'option': data.CALLPUT(),
                'strikeprice': data.STRIKEPRICE()
        };
```